# How to configure awslogs to send my apps' stdout & stderr to CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

according to 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_cloudwatch_logs.html

I can install **awslogs** agent to send logs to CloudWatch and monitor common files, but it seems to be missing the instructions to send logs from the stdout & err of my app. I don't want to write to disk and risk filling up its capacity. I'm using KubeOne + Terraform and I don't want to touch on EKS.

Also, how I can make sure system logs wa

```
[/var/log/dmesg]
file = /var/log/dmesg
log_group_name = /var/log/dmesg
log_stream_name = {cluster}/{container_instance_id}
```

Comment: what is ur app? If it's ecs service, you can do like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_LogConfiguration.html

Comment: it's a node/ionic behind a Nginx reverse proxy microservice with "error_log /dev/stdout debug;" in nginx.conf